# I want to find if a word exists in a file

Tags: files, grep, find, directory, for

I have a directory with some files. 
I want to know if a word exists in each file.
`$1` is my directory that I give it as a parameter

e.g. ./myscript.sh /mnt/c/User/er/Desktop/shows

I have written this code but the terminal shows this error : `[: it21754 :binary operator expected`

```
#!/bin/bash
for a in $( find "$1" -type f )
do
      if[ egrep 'it21754' $a ]
      then 
          echo "0" 
      else 
          echo "1"
      fi 
done
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what behavior you're looking for. Do you really want to output a 0 or 1 for every file in the directory? Once you fix the error and this is successful, you will get a series of 0s and 1s, and it won't be immediately obvious which files contain the word you're looking for.  If you could describe your desired output, you'll be more likely to get a helpful answer.

Answer (score 4):

Don't loop over the output of `find`. It's rather inelegant as the complete `find` command has to finish and produce *all* its output before the loop can even run its first iteration.  Furthermore you disqualify your script from working correctly with filenames that contain spaces.  The result of the command substitution would be split on spaces to produce words for the loop to loop over.

Instead, let the `find` command generate filenames for the loop like this:

```
find "$1" -type f -exec sh -c '...loop here...' sh {} +
```

We'll come back to this shortly.

The syntax on the line

```
if[ egrep 'it21754' $a ]
```

is a bit wonky, and you definitely do not need `egrep` here (`grep` is enough).

By "wonky" I mean that a `[ ... ]` test usually looks like `[ op arg ]` or `[ arg op arg ]` where `op` is some operator like `-f` or `-eq` or `=` and `arg` is a string.  You use `egrep` and `it21754` and whatever `$a` expands to, which is what generates the error that you get.  You can't run `egrep` in this context really, and you don't need to.

The correct `if`-statement is

```
if grep -qwF 'it21754' "$a"; then
    echo 0
else
    echo 1
fi
```

The `-qwF` flags makes `grep` quiet (`-q`), it makes it match using string comparisons rather than regular expressions (`-F`), and it assures that the string matched will be a complete word rather than a substring (`-w`).  Here we use the exit status of `grep` to choose whether to output a 0 (for a match) or 1 (for no match).

I've also double quoted `$a` as `"$a"` just in case the filename contains any spaces or filename globbing characters.

Interestingly enough, those are the numbers that `grep` uses for its exit status anyway, so we could shorten the whole thing to just

```
grep -qwF 'it21754' "$a"
echo "$?"
```

The `$?` variable holds the exit status of the most recently executed command.

Plugging that into our `find` command, we get

```
find "$1" -type f -exec sh -c '
    for a do
        grep -qwF "it21754" "$a"
        echo "$?"
    done' sh {} +
```

This will produce a number of ones and zeroes depending on whether the files contain the given word or not.  However, I think you may be looking for the filenames of the files that contain the word rather than a zero or a one.  For that we may use

```
find "$1" -type f -exec grep -lwF 'it21754' {} +
```

Here, I've changed the `-q` to a `-l` ("dash ell").  This calls `grep` with the found files and `grep` will *only* output the filenames of the ones that contains the given word. We don't need the `sh -c` bit any longer since we're calling a single utility (not `grep` *and* `echo`).

Of course, you could do the same thing with *just* `grep`:

```
grep -R -lwF 'it21754' "$1"
```

With `-R`, `grep` will search the subdirectories given on the command line recursively.

It may be worth noting that the `-w` and `-R` flags of `grep` are not standard, but implemented by the most common `grep` variants.

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

Comment: re: `grep` is enough, it looks like the OP is actually looking for a literal match, rather than a pattern match, so even `fgrep` is enough.

Comment: @DeNovo This is what the last command does. `grep -F` is equivalent to `fgrep`.

Comment: Ahh yes, I see you used the -F flag now. I had just skimmed to see if there was any need for me to hit submit on the answer I was working on. You may want to clarify that by "the `[ egrep 'it21754' $a ]` syntax is wonky", you mean that is what is throwing the error. There's a lot of text in this (excellent) answer. It may be helpful to call attention to the command that is throwing the error.

Comment: @DeNovo Thanks. I will expand on the "wonky" bit.